# What is the best way to check if element in list of lists is present in another list of lists based oon a value of a list

Tags: python, arrays

I currently have a list of lists (let's name it "big") that is about 9 columns and 5000 rows and growing. I have another list (let's name this one "small") that has approximately 3000 elements. My goal is to return each row in big where big[8] can be found in small. The results will be stored in a list of lists.
I have used list comprehension which has been returning the proper output, but it is far too inefficient for my needs. It takes several seconds to process these 5000 rows (usually about 6.5 seconds, and its efficiency gets worse with larger lists), and it needs to be able to quickly handle hundreds of thousands of rows.
The list comprehension I wrote is:

results = [row for row in big if row[8] in small]

Sample data of list of lists (big):

```
[[23.4, 6.8, 9.0, 13.0, 4.0, 19.0, 2.5, 7.6, 1472709600000], 
[32.1, 15.5, 17.7, 21.7, 12.7, 27.7, 11.2, 16.3, 1472882400000], 
[40.8, 24.2, 26.4, 30.4, 21.4, 36.4, 19.9, 25.0, 1473055200000], 
[49.5, 32.9, 35.1, 39.1, 30.1, 45.1, 28.6, 33.7, 1473228000000], 
[58.2, 41.6, 43.8, 47.8, 38.8, 53.8, 37.3, 42.4, 1473400800000]]
```

Sample data of list (small):

```
[[0.0, 11.7, 32.3, 22.2, 33.6, 44.7, 55.7, 66.3, 1472709600000],
 [0.0, 11.3, 32.4, 22.5, 33.6, 44.6, 55.3, 68, 1473055200000]]
```

Desired output (results):

```
[[23.4, 6.8, 9.0, 13.0, 4.0, 19.0, 2.5, 7.6, 1472709600000],  [40.8,
24.2, 26.4, 30.4, 21.4, 36.4, 19.9, 25.0, 1473055200000]]
```

Is there a more efficient way to return each row that has its last element found in another list?

Comment: Does `small` change often or remain the same most of the time? If it doesn't change often, and order doesn't matter, you should consider replacing it with a set, as membership testing is faster for a set. Since it's small, you can also consider keeping a set next to the list, if you need the order for the list. Also, if you only ever check the `[8]` element for each list from `big`, consider storing the list as a tuple of `(row[8], row)` in the big list. Access to tuples is slightly faster than access to lists. Again, whether this is a good idea depends on how often things change.

Comment: More generally: why do you need to return this filtered list? And how often? Does it make sense to just maintain a `small_big` list that only has the lists where `[8]` is in `small` and keep it up to date alongside `big`? After all, 5000x9 isn't exactly big, considering you just have tiny chunks of information (floats apparently) in there. The best way to do something is often avoiding having to do it at all.